# Play2 and Scala (Jerkson) - List of JsObjects - how to convert to a Json object

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I can't see the answer to this - is there an easy way to do this? I want to take a list of some object x and turn it into a single json object without any hacky code? I was doing some ugly stuff but would like to get this list into an object called 'data'. Can I somehow map this to the object "data"?

```
  private def renderArticleJson(articles: Iterable[GraphedArticle]): String = {

    val listToConvert = for (article <- articles) yield {
      JsObject(
        "articleId" -> Json.toJson(article.getArticleId)
        :: "articleUrl" -> Json.toJson(article.getArticleUrl)
        :: "graphId" -> Json.toJson(article.asVertex().getId.toString)
        :: "fullName" -> Json.toJson(article.getTitle)
        :: "imageUrl" -> Json.toJson(article.getImageUrl)
        :: Nil
      )
    }
  }
```

edited as requested: added what I would like to get out (solved now thanks to first answer's help)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "articleId": null,
      "articleUrl": null,
      "graphId": "#8:24",
      "fullName": "hey",
      "imageUrl": "hey"
    },
    {
      "articleId": null,
      "articleUrl": null,
      "graphId": "#8:25",
      "fullName": "hey",
      "imageUrl": "hey"
    },
    {
      "articleId": "b23c162d-b0af-4ce3-aebf-f33943492f95",
      "articleUrl": null,
      "graphId": "#8:26",
      "fullName": "hey",
      "imageUrl": "hey"
    },
    {
      "articleId": "8afe310c-8337-4a8a-8406-5670249ba0a7",
      "articleUrl": "hey",
      "graphId": "#8:27",
      "fullName": "hey",
      "imageUrl": "hey"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you add the resulting string you would like to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
private def renderArticleJson(articles: Iterable[GraphedArticle]): String = {

  val listToConvert = for (article <- articles) yield {
    JsObject(
      "articleId" -> Json.toJson(article.getArticleId)
        :: "articleUrl" -> Json.toJson(article.getArticleUrl)
        :: "graphId" -> Json.toJson(article.asVertex().getId.toString)
        :: "fullName" -> Json.toJson(article.getTitle)
        :: "imageUrl" -> Json.toJson(article.getImageUrl)
        :: Nil)
  }

  val jsonList = Json.toJson(listToConvert)
  Json.stringify(jsonList)
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. 
Here is the method I ended up with

Comment: Just a note that listToConvert has to be seq so you have to .toSeq it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to EEColor I did get what I wanted. I gave him the answer but the final code I used is as follows:

```
  private def renderArticleJson(articles: Iterable[GraphedArticle]): String = {


    val listToConvert = for (article <- articles) yield {
      JsObject(
        "articleId" -> Json.toJson(article.getArticleId)
          :: "articleUrl" -> Json.toJson(article.getArticleUrl)
          :: "graphId" -> Json.toJson(article.asVertex().getId.toString)
          :: "fullName" -> Json.toJson(article.getTitle)
          :: "imageUrl" -> Json.toJson(article.getImageUrl)
          :: Nil)
    }

    val jsonList = Json.toJson(listToConvert.toSeq)
    val result = JsObject("data" -> jsonList :: Nil)
    Json.stringify(result)
}
```